Find an example to illustrate that the isomorphism type of a semidirect product cannot determine the isomorphism types of its kernel and image
I am sorry for my poor English. If I have any problems with the expression, please point out. I will appreciate any helps.

Let $H,K$ be two groups, $\varphi :K \rightarrow Aut(H)$ a homomorphism. I am interested in the influence of $ker(\varphi)$ and $im(\varphi)$ on $H \rtimes_{\varphi} K$. Firstly, I considered whether kernel and image can determine a semidirect product. The following is the formal description：
(Question 1): Let $H,K$ be two groups, $\varphi_{i} :K \rightarrow Aut(H)$ be homomorphisms for $i=1,2$. If $ker(\varphi_{1})=ker(\varphi_{2})$ and $im(\varphi_{1})=im(\varphi_{2})$, can we say that $H \rtimes_{\varphi_{1}} K \simeq H \rtimes_{\varphi_{2}} K$ ?
The answer is no and I wrote my proof below.
After that, I began to consider the opposite side of Quesion 1, whether the isomorphism type of a semidirect product can determine the isomorphism types of its kernel and image? The following is the formal description：
(Question 2): Let $H,K$ be two groups, $\varphi_{i} :K \rightarrow Aut(H)$ be homomorphisms for $i=1,2$. If $H \rtimes_{\varphi_{1}} K \simeq H \rtimes_{\varphi_{2}} K$, can we say that $ker(\varphi_{1}) \simeq ker(\varphi_{2})$ or $im(\varphi_{1}) \simeq im(\varphi_{2})$ ?
I guess the answer is also no, i.e., there exist $H,K,\varphi_{1},\varphi_{2}$ such that $H \rtimes_{\varphi_{1}} K \simeq H \rtimes_{\varphi_{2}} K$, but $ker(\varphi_{1}) \ncong ker(\varphi_{2})$ and $im(\varphi_{1}) \ncong im(\varphi_{2})$. By below lemmas, I can claim that the proper counterexample certainly does not exist if $gcd(|H|,|K|)=1$. So we have to satisfy that $gcd(|H|,|K|) \neq 1$ or there is an infinite group between $H$ and $K$. That's all I can think about. Could you construct a proper counterexample, preferably using finite groups?

The following all content is my proof about Question 1
(Lemma 1): Let $H,K,A,B$ be groups, $\varphi :K \rightarrow Aut(H)$, $\phi :B \rightarrow Aut(A)$, $f:H \rightarrow A$, $g:K \rightarrow B$ be homomorphisms, then $(f,g): H \rtimes_{\varphi} K \rightarrow A \rtimes_{\phi} B$, $(h,k) \mapsto (f(h),g(k))$ is a homomorphism if and only if the following equivalent conditions hold:

$f(k\cdot_{\varphi}h)=g(k)\cdot_{\phi}f(h)$ for all $k \in K$, $h \in H$;
the following diagram commutes, in which we define set-theoretic maps $f_{*}:Aut(H) \rightarrow Hom(H,A), \sigma \mapsto f \circ \sigma$ and $f^{*}:Aut(A) \rightarrow Hom(H,A), \tau \mapsto \tau \circ f$,

\begin{array}{ccccc}
K & \xrightarrow{\varphi} & Aut(H) & \xrightarrow{f_{*}} & Hom(H,A) \\\
\downarrow{g} & & & & \downarrow{id} \\\
B & \xrightarrow{\phi} & Aut(A) & \xrightarrow{f^{*}} & Hom(H,A) \\\
\end{array}

Proof of lemma: $(f,g)$ is a homomorphism
$\Leftrightarrow$ $(f,g)((h_{1},k_{1}))\cdot_{A \rtimes_{\phi} B}(f,g)((h_{2},k_{2})) = 
 (f,g)((h_{1},k_{1})\cdot_{H \rtimes_{\varphi} K}(h_{2},k_{2}))$ for all $h_{1},h_{2} \in 
 H$, $k_{1},k_{2} \in K$
$\Leftrightarrow$ $(f(h_{1})(g(k_{1})\cdot_{\phi}f(h_{2})),g(k_{1})g(k_{2})) = (f(h_{1})f(k_{1}\cdot_{\varphi}h_{2}),g(k_{1})g(k_{2}))$ for all $h_{1},h_{2} \in 
 H$, $k_{1},k_{2} \in K$
$\Leftrightarrow$ $f(k\cdot_{\varphi}h)=g(k)\cdot_{\phi}f(h)$ for all $k \in K$, $h \in H$. And it's easy to verify that the commutativity of the diagram above is equivalent to condition $1$.

Remark of Lemma $1$: If $f$, $g$ are isomorphisms in addition, then $(f,g)$ is also an isomorphism, $f^{*}$ exists inverse map $(f^{-1})^{*}$, we can define homomorphism $c_f: Aut(H) \rightarrow Aut(K), \sigma \mapsto ((f^{*})^{-1} \circ f_{*})(\sigma) = f \circ \sigma \circ f^{-1}$, and the diagram above can be replaced by:
\begin{array}{ccc}
K & \xrightarrow{\varphi} & Aut(H) \\\
\downarrow{g} & & \downarrow{c_{f}} \\\
B & \xrightarrow{\phi} & Aut(A) \\\
\end{array}
(Lemma 2): Let $H,K$ be two finite groups with $gcd(|H|,|K|)=1$, $\varphi_{i} :K \rightarrow Aut(H)$ be homomorphisms for $i=1,2$. If $H \rtimes_{\varphi_{1}} K \simeq H \rtimes_{\varphi_{2}} K$, then there exist $\alpha \in Aut(H)$, $\beta \in Aut(K)$ such that $(\alpha , \beta): H \rtimes_{\varphi_{1}} K \rightarrow H \rtimes_{\varphi_{2}} K$ is an isomorphism, i.e., the following diagram commutes:
\begin{array}{ccc}
K & \xrightarrow{\varphi_{1}} & Aut(H) \\\
\downarrow{\beta} & & \downarrow{c_{\alpha}} \\\
K & \xrightarrow{\varphi_{2}} & Aut(H) \\\
\end{array}

This is a theorem by Taunt (in "Remarks on the Isomorphism Problem in the Theories of Construction of Finite Groups"). I first learned it at here. Although I have no ability to read the original article, but I can prove Lemma $2$ when $H$ is a $p$-group, $K$ is a $q$-group for different primes $p$, $q$.

Now, we can construct a counterexample of Question $1$ naturally by using above lemmas.
Counterexample of Question 1: Consider groups $H,K$ with $gcd(|H|,|K|)=1$, let $\varphi_{i} :K \rightarrow Aut(H)$ be homomorphisms for $i=1,2$ such that $ker(\varphi_{1})=ker(\varphi_{2})=ker$ and $im(\varphi_{1})=im(\varphi_{2})=im$. We can decompose $\varphi_{i}$ canonically, $\varphi_{i} = \iota_{i} \circ \pi_{i}$ for $i=1,2$, in which $\pi_{1} = \pi_{2} = \pi$. By Lemmas 1 and 2, $H \rtimes_{\varphi_{1}} K \simeq H \rtimes_{\varphi_{2}} K$ if and only if there exist $\alpha \in Aut(H)$, $\beta \in Aut(K)$ such the following diagram commutes:
\begin{array}{ccccc}
K & \xrightarrow{\pi} & K/ker & \xrightarrow{\iota_{1}} & Aut(H) \\\
\downarrow{\beta} & & & & \downarrow{c_{\alpha}} \\\
K & \xrightarrow{\pi} & K/ker & \xrightarrow{\iota_{2}} & Aut(H) \\\
\end{array}
If we require $Inn(Aut(H))=1$, then $c_{\alpha}$ can only be $id_{Aut(H)}$, meanwhile, $im(\iota_{1})=im(\iota_{2})$ and the diagram above commute if and only if the following one commutes: (Let $(\iota_2)^{-1}_{l}$ be the left inverse map of $\iota_{2}$ and define $\theta := (\iota_2)^{-1}_{l} \circ \iota_{1}$)
\begin{array}{ccc}
K & \xrightarrow{\pi} & K/ker \\\
\downarrow{\beta} &  & \downarrow{\theta} \\\
K & \xrightarrow{\pi} & K/ker \\\
\end{array}
Furthermore, if we choose proper $\iota_{1}$ and $\iota_{2}$ such that $\theta = (\iota_2)^{-1}_{l} \circ \iota_{1}$ cannot be lifted to $Aut(K)$, then there must be $H \rtimes_{\varphi_{1}} K \ncong H \rtimes_{\varphi_{2}} K$ by Lemma $2$, but meanwhile, we have $ker(\varphi_{1})=ker(\varphi_{2})$ and $im(\varphi_{1})=im(\varphi_{2})$.
Let $K = D_{8} = \left \langle r,s \right \rangle$, $ker(\varphi_{1})=ker(\varphi_{2})=\left \langle r^{2} \right \rangle$, there exist $\theta \in Aut(D_{8}/\left \langle r^2 \right \rangle) \simeq Aut(V_4)$ such that $\theta$ cannot be lifted to $Aut(D_{8})$:
$$
\theta : D_{8}/\left \langle r^2 \right \rangle \rightarrow D_{8}/\left \langle r^2 \right \rangle, \overline{r} \mapsto \overline{s}, \overline{s} \mapsto \overline{r}, \overline{sr} \mapsto \overline{sr}
$$
It's easy to verify that $\theta$ cannot be lifted to $Aut(D_{8})$.
Let $H = Z_{15}$. Since $Aut(Z_{15}) \simeq Aut(Z_3) \times Aut(Z_5) \simeq Z_{2} \times Z_{4}$, an abelian group, we can derive that $Inn(Aut(H))=1$, and it's easy to find $V \le Aut(Z_{15})$ such that $V \simeq V_{4}$.
Let $\pi_{i}$ be the canonical projection of $D_8 \rightarrow D_8/\left \langle r^2 \right \rangle$ for $i=1,2$ and define $\pi := \pi_{1} = \pi_{2}$.
Let $\iota_{2}$ be an injective homomorphism of $D_{8}/\left \langle r^2 \right \rangle$ into $Aut(Z_{15})$ such that $im(\iota_{2})=V$, and let $\iota_{1} := \iota_{2} \circ \theta$.
Since $gcd(|Z_{15}|,|D_{8}|)=1$, we can conclude that $Z_{15} \rtimes_{\varphi_{1}=\iota_{1}\circ\pi_{1}} D_8 \ncong Z_{15} \rtimes_{\varphi_{2}=\iota_{2}\circ\pi_{2}} D_8$, but $ker(\varphi_{1})=ker(\varphi_{2})=\left \langle r^2 \right \rangle$, $im(\varphi_{1})=im(\varphi_{2})=V$.
\begin{array}{ccc}
D_8 & \xrightarrow{\pi} & D_8/\left \langle r^2 \right \rangle \\\
 &  & \downarrow{\theta} \\\
D_8 & \xrightarrow{\pi} & D_8/\left \langle r^2 \right \rangle \\\
\end{array}
$\Box$

What's kernel and image?

@non-euclideangeometry $ker$ and $im$ are shorthands of $ker(\varphi_{1})=ker(\varphi_{2})$ and $im(\varphi_{1})=im(\varphi_{2})$ respectively. In the last constructed example, $ker(\varphi_{1})=ker(\varphi_{2})=\left \langle r^2 \right \rangle$ and $im(\varphi_{1})=im(\varphi_{2})=V$, $V$ is a subgroup of $Aut(Z_{15})$ such that $V \simeq V_4$.

Ok, so it requires alot of reading.   On its own the title doesn't mean much.

@non-euclideangeometry Sorry, I mistook your meaning. The meanings of ''kernel'' and ''image'' in title are as follows: Let $H \rtimes_{\varphi} K$ be a semidirect product, we define the ''kernel'' of $H \rtimes_{\varphi} K$ as $ker(\varphi)$, and define the ''image'' of $H \rtimes_{\varphi} K$ as $im(\varphi)$.

Let $S_3$ be the symmetric group on $3$ elements and let $C_2$ be the cyclic group of order $2$. Consider the following two homomorphisms $C_2 \to \operatorname{Aut}(S_3)$:

$\varphi_1$ is the trivial homomorphism, i.e. $\operatorname{ker}(\varphi_1) = C_2$ and $\operatorname{im}(\varphi_1) = 1$.
$\varphi_2$ maps $C_2$ to a subgroup of $\operatorname{Inn}(S_3)$ of order $2$, such that $\operatorname{ker}(\varphi_2) = 1$ and $\left|\operatorname{im}(\varphi_2)\right| = 2$.

Clearly $S_3 \rtimes_{\varphi_1} C_2$ is just the direct product $S_3 \times C_2$. But, as this answer shows, the semidirect product $S_3 \rtimes_{\varphi_2} C_2$ is also isomorphic to the direct product $S_3 \times C_2$.
Thus, we have that $S_3 \rtimes_{\varphi_1} C_2 \cong S_3 \rtimes_{\varphi_2} C_2$, but $\operatorname{ker}(\varphi_1) \neq \operatorname{ker}(\varphi_2)$ and $\operatorname{im}(\varphi_1) \neq \operatorname{im}(\varphi_2)$.

Another family of examples are obtained by taking a finite nonabelian simple group $S$ and considering any semidirect product $S\rtimes S$.
Theorem. If $S$ is a finite nonabelian simple group, then any semidirect product $S\rtimes S$ is isomorphic to $S\times S$.
Proof. To avoid confusion, let us write $G=N\rtimes H$, where both $N$ and $H$ are isomorphic to $S$.
Letting $G$ act by conjugation on $N$, we get a morphism $G\to \mathrm{Aut}(N)$ which contains $\mathrm{Inn}(N)\cong N$. The kernel is $C_G(N)$, and since $N$ is nonabelian and simple, $C_G(N)\cap N = \{1\}$, so $NC_G(N) = N\times C_G(N)$. Since $N$ is normal in $G$, $C_G(N)\triangleleft G$, so the image of $C_G(N)$ in $G/N\cong H$ is normal in $H$, and so must either equal $H$ or be trivial (since $H\cong S$ is simple).
If the image is trivial, then $G$ embeds into $\mathrm{Aut}(N)$, and the composition $G\to\mathrm{Aut}(N)\to\mathrm{Out}(N)$ embeds $H$ (which is isomorphic to $S$) into $\mathrm{Out}(N)$. By Schreier's conjecture, a consequence of the Classification of Finite Simple Groups, $\mathrm{Out}(N)$ is solvable, so it cannot have a subgroup isomorphic to $H$, a contradiction. Thus, the image of $C_G(N)$ in $H$ cannot be trivial, so the image is $H$. But that  means that $G=N\times C_G(N) \cong N\times H \cong S\times S$, as desired. $\Box$
(If you don't want to use Schreier's Conjecture, then note that we can certainly do the above for $A_n$, $n\geq 5$, since the outer automorphism group has order either $2$ or $4$)
So now we can compare $S\rtimes_{\varphi}S$ where $\varphi(s)$ is conjugation by $s$,  which has $\ker(\varphi)=\{1\}$ and $\mathrm{Im}(\varphi)=\mathrm{Inn}(S)$; with $S\times S$ which has $\ker(\varphi)=S$ and $\mathrm{Im}(\varphi)=\{1\}$.
(For example, if you let $A_5$ act on itself by conjugation and construct $A_5\rtimes A_5$, then the subgroup $N=\{(\sigma,1)\mid \sigma\in A_5\}$ and the subgroup $K=\{(\rho^{-1},\rho)\mid \rho\in A_5\}$ are two subgroups of $A_5\rtimes A_5$, both isomorphic to $A_5$, with trivial intersection, and they centralize each other, so $A_5\rtimes A_5\cong H\times K\cong A_5\times A_5$.)
